# problem with passing numeric parameter to web service from java client

Tags: java, web-services, client, axis

i try to passing numeric parameter to a web service that receive the value and return it back. 
this is the snippet of the web method :

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getNumber")
public Integer getNumber(@WebParam(name = "i")
Integer i) {
    //TODO write your implementation code here:
    System.out.println("number : "+i);
    return i;
}
```

an this is the snippet of my client code :

```
    Map results = FastMap.newInstance();
    results.put("result", "success");

    String endPoint = "http://localhost:8084/ProvideWS/MathWS";
    URL endpoint=null;
    try{
        endpoint = new URL(endPoint);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        org.ofbiz.base.util.Debug.log("Location not a valid URL "+e);
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    Service service = null;
    Call call = null;
    try{
        service = new Service();

        call = (Call)service.createCall();
        call.setTargetEndpointAddress(endpoint);
        String nameSpace = "http://ws/";

        String serviceName = "getNumber";

        call.setOperationName(new QName(nameSpace, serviceName));

        call.addParameter("i",org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_INTEGER , ParameterMode.IN);
        call.setReturnType(org.apache.axis.Constants.XSD_INTEGER);

        Object msg[] = new Object[]{new Integer(5)};    
        for (Object o : msg) {
            org.ofbiz.base.util.Debug.log("object to be sent===== "+o.toString());
        }
        Object ret = call.invoke(msg);
        results.put("result", "result : "+ ret.toString());

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        org.ofbiz.base.util.Debug.log("exc when running soap client test : "+e);
        results.put("result", "error : "+e);
    }
    return results;
```

the problem is the return value in the client always 0 (the server received the number as zero), the method i used to pass the parameter works fine when the paramater is String. I.ve tried to hard-coding the return value in server and the output in client is fine, so i thought it must be how the server retrieved the parameter is the problem.

do you have any idea why this is happen and how to solve this?

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is causing your problem.  But the first thing I would do would be to try to capture the actual request that is being sent to the server.  That should give you some clues as to whether the root problem is on the client or server side.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I've just solved the problem, it because of the mismatch encoding between the client and the server like said in discussion [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=333757&start=0&tstart=0). I solved it by adding code `call.setEncoding(null);`. Sorry for the trouble.